# Word tokenizer for Python implementation of hedonometer

Tags: python, tokenize, sentiment-analysis

I'm studying [this paper](https://epjdatascience.springeropen.com/articles/10.1140/epjds/s13688-016-0093-1) "The emotional arcs of stories are dominated by six basic shapes", in which a hedonometer (previosly used mainly for sentiment analysis on Twitter) is applied to a book to make an emotional arc.

I'm trying to reproduce the results of such paper in Python, but, while I understand the hedonometer algorithm, I can't understand the way words were tokenized (the paper is really poor on this matter, and I'm not really confident about it).

In the link above, at the bottom, there is the [Electronic Supplementary Material](https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1140%2Fepjds%2Fs13688-016-0093-1/MediaObjects/13688_2016_93_MOESM1_ESM.pdf) in which, at page S8, it is claimed that the book ["The Picture of Dorian Gray"](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/174/pg174.txt) (after removing the front and back matter) has 84,591 words.

I tried two tokenizers (suppose the text is in a variable `text`).

The first is a naive one

```
words = text.split()
```

and gets only 78,934 words.

The second one, using a well-know library (the code might by sub-optimal, since I've never used NLTK before neither done anything related to Natural Language Processing)

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
words = [word for sent in sent_tokenize(text) for word in word_tokenize(sent)]
```

I get an incredible amount of 95,285 words! If I filter out the punctuation with the following code

```
words2 = [word for word in words if word not in ',-.:\'\"!?;()[]']
```

it reduces to 83,141 words.

Yet, nothing really close to the paper quantity of 84,591 words. What am I doing wrong? Am I not understading how a tokenizer works?

P.S. I've tried with other books, but the results are similar. I always either underestimate or overestimate the words count by 2000 words.

Bonus question: as the paper points out, there is a dictionary of words with associated happiness score to be used (to assign averaged happiness score at chunks of text). In such dictionary there are also words such as "can't", while the NLTK tokenizer splits "can't" into "ca" and "n't". Also, looking at the tokenized text on page S5 of the Electronic Supplementary Material I assume that the NLTK behaviour is the desired one. Yet, shouldn't it work otherwise, i.e. leaving "can't" united, by the way the dictionary is built?

Comment: You could email the authors.

Comment: I'm seding an email now.
Should I write to one of the authors or all of them?